# Linksys AE1200 stops detecting hotspots

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-router, network-adapter

I have a Linksys E1200 router and Linksys AE1200 USB adapter and I am running Windows 7 x64.

Periodically my connection drops and I have to either use the Windows 7 troubleshooter, or unplug/replug the USB adapter. When this happens all the hotspots within range disappear from the list in the system tray. I live in an apartment building with usually 6-10 hotspots within range.

Is this a known problem that can be fixed?

Comment: You can switch to 5GHz but that requires new hardware. But if the problem is an interference problem the new hardware will solve it.  Be sure you purchase dual-band hardware.

Comment: How come I can no longer see other networks in my area? Even if I cannot connect to my own router, I should still be able to see everyone else's, no?